# Need a way to get GPS coordinates from an address on iPhone CoreLocation

Tags: iphone, gps, geocoding, core-location

Everyone makes a big deal about getting an address from GPS coordinates (reverse geocoding), and they're right to do so; it's really neat. But I've had a lot of trouble finding any way to do the reverse process (regular geocoding?) within the iOS SDK. Am I being really dumb? Is there a way to do it? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you check out the iOS 5 beta release notes.

Comment: Good call. I particularly recommend the WWDC videos. They explained everything I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind using the Google API, I would look at the MapKit framework in the iOS SDK - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008323